# Delete on Laravel with Join Condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can insert, update and delete in Laravel for sure but I don't know why in this case i get stuck, so please share your mind here. here was my function

```
public function hapuskeluhan($id){

    $keluh = keluhan::findOrFail($id);
    $tindak = tindakan::where('id_keluhan',$id)->get();
    $analisa = analisa::join('tindakans','tindakans.id','=','analisas.id_tindakan')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->where('keluhans.id','=',$id)->get();
    //dd($analisa);

    $keluh->delete();
    $tindak->delete();
    $analisa->delete();
    \Session::flash('flash_message','Data successfully deleted.');
    return redirect('lihatkeluhan');
}
```

i got error when delete $analisa... please kindly help

Comment: why use join for delete?? how can laravel know which record of the two you joined to delete?

Comment: check this for join delete in laravel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802662/delete-rows-with-laravel-query-builder-and-left-join

Comment: If you're going to use eloquent then you should not join, you should define relationships and then select a model on condition of those relationships. Eloquent will sort things out for you if you do that.

Comment: How are your models defined?

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for replay but i confuse how to fix cause i must join 2 table at the same time

Comment: @ChristianusAndre read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships . All of it. Don't skim through it. Read it.

Comment: Table Analisa has id_tindakan i must Join Tindakan 1st (Join Tindakan Where analisa.id_tindakan = tindakan.id) then join again Keluhan (Join Keluhan where tindakan.id_keluhan = Keluhan.id) after that delete

Comment: Always use English language in coding for better undestanding @Christianus Andre